# Storing matrices in mysql for fast full matrices retrival

Tags: mysql, matrix

In a project, there is a time consuming computation result that is represented in a numeric matrix format, which can be commonly used in follow-on tasks. So, I want to store the calculation result into the database, so the new tasks can re-use the result.

The size of matrix is not fixed and there will be multiple matrices.

Which one is more suitable for my case?

1. Storing serialized matrix.
2. Create a table like follows:

```
Matrix ID
X-coord
Y-coord
Value
```

Or maybe there might be better ways?

Comment: If single elements of the matrix are to be updated frequently, then the second model is easier to use.

Comment: @TheImpaler sorry, I forgot to mention, the matrix should also be updated as a whole instead of updading individual cells. In this case, is the first one a better choice?

Answer (score 0):

(A short discussion of option 1.)

If MySQL does not need to look at the cells of a matrix, then serialize it in any form and store it in a `TEXT` or `BLOB` column in the table.

JSON is a relatively simple serialization that is available in a lot of programming languages and is easily readable by humans.  XML is, in my opinion, too clunky to consider.

Or you could do something ad-hoc such as numbers separated by commas.  And start the string with the length and width of the matrix, followed by the values in order.  (No need for x and y coordinates.)  When reading, your language may have a "split()" or "explode()" function to break the string apart on ",".

Comment: Thanks for your advice, I think maybe I should give a try for the last one, it seems to be faster compared to JSON or XML. Human readable is not quite important for me since this value is used only for further calculation.